# How can I implement a data structure that preserves order and has fast insertion/removal?

Tags: python, data-structures, python-3.x, deque

I'm looking for a data structure that preserves the order of its elements (which may change over the life of the data structure, as the client may move elements around).

It should allow fast search, insertion before/after a given element, removal of a given element, lookup of the first and last elements, and bidirectional iteration starting at a given element.

What would be a good implementation?

Here's my first attempt:

A class deriving from both `collections.abc.Iterable` and `collections.abc.MutableSet` that contains a linked list and a dictionary. The dictionary's keys are elements, values are nodes in the linked list. The dictionary would handle search for a node given an element. Once an element is found, the linked list would handle insertion before/after, deletion, and iteration. The dictionary would be updated by adding or deleting the relevant key/value pair. Clearly, with this approach the elements must be hashable and unique (or else, we'll need another layer of indirection where each element is represented by an auto-assigned numeric identifier, and only those identifiers are stored as keys).

It *seems to me* that this would be strictly better in asymptotic complexity than either `list` or `collections.deque`, but I may be wrong. [EDIT: Wrong, as pointed out by @roliu. Unlike `list` or `deque`, I would not be able to find an element by its numeric index in `O(1)`. As of now, it is `O(N)` but I am sure there's some way to make it `O(log N)` if necessary.]

Comment: `collections.OrderedDictionary` is a dict using doubly-linked lists to maintain order. However, rearranging the order arbitrarily is not trivial.

Comment: How would do fast insertion with your dictionary + linked list? Any abstract data structure built on a balanced binary search tree seems like it'd work for you (it's reasonably fast for insertion, removal, search and can be iterated forwards and backwards from any node). Not sure what there is in python though.

Comment: As it stands this question has some faults: it is too broad (multiple questions in one post), asks for external resources (explicitly off-topic) and is not a practical code problem (better suited to Programmers.SE).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think its `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, `OrderedDict` doesn't allow insertion except at the end, so I can't use it. @roliu: I thought insertion would be as simple as finding the desired location, adding a new node to the doubly linked list at that location, and storing the element, node as a new key, value in the dictionary.

Comment: @roliu: I thought balanced binary search tree assumes that the order relationship between elements is fixed for the life of the tree. If I decide to move an element to a different position, it might require a very expensive rebuild of the entire tree, no? In addition, binary search tree is O(log N), while hash is O(1). Of course, if something is wrong with my hash implementation attempt, then I'll have to try trees.

Comment: Very expensive rebuild: no, in order to move an element, you remove it from the tree (O(log n)) and then re-insert it at another position (O(log n)).

Comment: @ArminRigo Sorry, I didn't explain my concern correctly. My concern was: how would I search for the element if there's no fixed ordering between elements? The binary search tree is only useful if I know which branch to take.

Comment: Ah, yes, I assumed that each element would have an orderable key.  You would then be able to remove the element by looking for it using the old orderable key, assuming that you still have it, before changing to a new orderable key and re-inserting it.  That doesn't work in all cases though.

Comment: @max: The issue with using a dictionary to find list nodes is that it can't help you with insertions, since in that situation you need to find the neighbors of your new node, and you don't know their keys, only the new node's. I don't think there's a data structure that can do ordered iteration along with fast inserts and removals other than some kind of search tree. For a perhaps heavy-weight implementation of those, you could look at a database module like `sqlite3` (which can work with in-memory databases, if you don't need persistence on disk and would like better speed).

Comment: @Blckknght: In each node, I was planning to store 3 things: the link to the previous node, the link to the next node, and the element. The element is the same as the key in the dictionary. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @max: The problem is, if you already added, say `1` and `3` to your dictionary (and their link list references point to each other), how do you find them if you want to add `2` in between? Looking up `2` in the dictionary won't find the node associated with `1` or `3` for you. You need a different data structure to find "where `2` should go", rather than `2` exactly.

Comment: @max I guess I misread your question. I'm a bit confused as to how you are going to define the ordering of the elements... is there a key or something on the elements that defines the ordering? If there isn't you can always attach one, e.g. `(sortKey, Elem)` and then do the remove/insert as suggested before. And Blckknght already explained the issue with the inserts. You can insert `2` really easily... how do you construct the corresponding node? You don't know what the `prev` and `next` pointers point to. Also, if you give actual #s for your program/application it'd make it easier to help

Comment: @roliu, Blckknght: I posted an example code that hopefully clarifies these points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly modified version of [Raymond Hettinger's OrderedSet recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576696/) seems to satisfy all my requirements. I only added support for position-based access and read/write.

```
# changes vs. original recipe at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576696/:
# added a position parameter to add
# changed how pop works, and added popleft
# added find, get_start, get_end, next_pos, prev_pos, __getitem__, __setitem__

class OrderedSetPlus(collections.MutableSet, collections.Iterable):
    '''
    >>> oset = OrderedSetPlus([3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8])
    >>> oset.add(13)
    >>> p = oset.find(2)
    >>> oset.add(15, p)
    >>> oset
    OrderedSetPlus([3, 15, 2, 1, 8, 13])
    >>> p = oset.next_pos(p)
    >>> oset[p]
    1
    >>> oset.add(7, p)
    >>> oset
    OrderedSetPlus([3, 15, 2, 7, 1, 8, 13])
    >>> oset[p] = 20
    >>> oset
    OrderedSetPlus([3, 15, 2, 7, 20, 8, 13])
    '''

    class DuplicateElement(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self.end = end = [] 
        end += [None, end, end]         # sentinel node for doubly linked list
        self.map = {}                   # key --> [key, prev, next]
        if iterable is not None:
            self |= iterable

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.map)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.map

    def find(self, key):
        return self.map.get(key, None)

    # inserts element before the specified position
    # if pos is None, inserts at the end
    # position can only be obtained by calling instance methods
    def add(self, key, pos = None):
        if pos is None:
            pos = self.end
        if key not in self.map:
            curr = pos[PREV]
            curr[NEXT] = pos[PREV] = self.map[key] = [key, curr, pos]

    def discard(self, key):
        if key in self.map:        
            key, prev, next = self.map.pop(key)
            prev[NEXT] = next
            next[PREV] = prev

    def __iter__(self):
        end = self.end
        curr = end[NEXT]
        while curr is not end:
            yield curr[KEY]
            curr = curr[NEXT]

    def get_end(self):
        return self.end[PREV]

    def get_start(self):
        return self.end[NEXT]

    def next_pos(self, pos):
        pos = pos[NEXT]
        return None if pos is self.end else pos

    def prev_pos(self, pos):
        pos = pos[PREV]
        return None if pos is self.end else pos

    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        return pos[KEY]

    def __setitem__(self, pos, key):
        if key in self.map:
            raise DuplicateElement
        pos[KEY] = key

    def __reversed__(self):
        end = self.end
        curr = end[PREV]
        while curr is not end:
            yield curr[KEY]
            curr = curr[PREV]

    def popleft(self):
        return self.pop(pos = self.get_start())


    def pop(self, pos=None):
        if not self:
            raise IndexError()
        if pos is None:
            pos = self.get_end()
        key = self[pos]
        #key = next(reversed(self)) if last else next(iter(self))
        self.discard(key)
        return key

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, list(self))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, OrderedSet):
            return len(self) == len(other) and list(self) == list(other)
        return set(self) == set(other)
```

Comment: Hm I'm confused. This isn't ordered as far as I can tell; I mean... `add()` takes a new key and an _existing node_ and you give the user the option to add to the end. Is this really the data structure you wanted? It looks like a map with a linked list that doesn't actually give you anything extra...

Comment: By "ordered" I meant that the order is arbitrarily determined by the client at the time new elements are added. It is not the same as "sorted" (where the client specifies a relationship and the data structure automatically sorts itself with each insertion). I know it's confusing, and I wish I knew a better term for this. In my defense I can point to Python's `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Mm the way your code handles ordering just reminds me of a basic list. In what way does it handle ordering differently from, say `ArrayList` in Java or `List` in C#? Anyways, looks like you got your answer. Cool!

Comment: @roliu I think the semantics is the same, but the time complexity of C# `List` is `O(N)` for removals. C# has a `SkipList`, which also has the same semantics but `O(log N)` complexity for all operations. So the data structure I wanted essentially replaces the trees with hash tables, resulting in amortized `O(1)` for all operations.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Just to be clear, I wouldn't say your data structure is "better" than a C# `List`. They're different--they don't even support the same operations. For instance, you can't add to an arbitrary index unless you already have the node that lies at that index. That's really unnatural for most use cases but may work great for yours. Similarly, you can't remove from an arbitrary index; you only support removing by key. I brought up `ArrayList` and `List` only to give an example of the ordering semantic, not to argue that they are equivalent to your data structure.

Comment: @roliu: Haha, I didn't even notice that! I got so excited that I can insert/remove by the element position, that I forgot that I lose access by the numeric index :)

Answer (score 1):

Using doubly-linked lists in Python is a bit uncommon.  However, your own proposed solution of a doubly-linked list and a dictionary has the correct complexity: all the operations you ask for are O(1).

I don't think there is in the standard library a more direct implementation.  Trees might be nice theoretically, but also come with drawbacks, like O(log n) or (precisely) their general absence from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I do know this isn't exactly a direct answer to your question (because this is not a python-implemented solution), but if your data structure is going to be rather large I'd consider a [Redis](http://redis.io) db. You can use [redis-pi](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) to talk to it from Python.